# Getting the activities on a video of another user with API v3 client library

Tags: youtube-api

For the purpose of stream mining, I want to get the time-stamped click-streams of views of a particular Youtube video of another user, so not of the logged in user. I checked the v3 Javascript client library and it seems to me it can only retrieve the activities of the current authenticated user. Is it true? Or am I missing something?
Can I get this with youtube.activities.list?

Answer (score 0):

Some channel activities are retrievable without having to have a user authenticate; if you hit this endpoint:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

then some of the reported activities that can be returned include uploads, bulletins, adding items to playlists, etc. Other activities you might wish to track will require that the user authenticate before the API will return it, however.